# pg_dump without setting search_path

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

When I use `pg_dump` to export schema from a database, it adds the following line at the beginning:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

Is it possible set an option where `pg_dump` will not add this line? It is causing issues later when I try to execute other SQL commands, without the schema qualifier.

This is the `pg_dump` command I am using right now:

```
pg_dump -O -x -h <db-host> -p <db-port> -U <db-user> -d <db-name> --schema public --schema-only > public-schema.sql
```

Comment: If, like me, you found this page while searching for the *reason* pg_dump does this, [here is the answer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ace62b19-f918-3579-3633-b9e19da8b9de%40aklaver.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option.

I recommend that you restore a dump with `psql -f dumpfile` rather than using `\i` to execute it in the current session.